# Two ArrayList in one ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

Please help me in putting two arraylist in one listview only. I only display the two columns from my database using two listview. Im not that good in programming so I need your help guys. Thanks in advance

THIS IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DataDB data = new DataDB();
ListView list;
ListView list2;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

public MainActivity() {
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    // set data

    ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        firstName = data.getFNameDB(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, firstName);

    // set the adapter
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    ArrayList<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        lastName = data.getLNameDB(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lastName);

    // set the adapter
    list2.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

THIS IS MY DATADB

```
public class DataDB {
DatabaseHelper con;
ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();

public DataDB() {
}


public ArrayList<String> getFNameDB(Context context) throws SQLException {
    this.con = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    try {
        this.con.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ;
    }

    if (!this.con.checkDataBase()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        this.con.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.con.getWritableDatabase();

        for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstName FROM tbl_doctor", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.firstName.add(cursor.getString(0))) {

        }


        this.con.close();
        return this.firstName;

    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getLNameDB(Context context) throws SQLException {
    this.con = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    try {
        this.con.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ;
    }

    if (!this.con.checkDataBase()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        this.con.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.con.getWritableDatabase();

        for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT lastName FROM tbl_doctor", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.lastName.add(cursor.getString(0))) {

        }

        this.con.close();
        return this.lastName;

    }

}
```

Comment: send both list in adapter constructor and loop the getView or bindView on size for list1+list2 and inflate the view accordingly, this is hint for you. Post the code you have tried so it will be more helpful

Comment: why are you writing different methods to access `firstname` and `lastname` ? any specific purpose ?

Comment: just like what i said in my question I'm not that good in programming so I followed the basic in retrieving the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear things out , what you should do is to use a single `ListView` and display both firstName and lastName in that, i will demonstrate some code for that , i will add the essential parts for you to understand things a better way,

In your method where you are accessing `firstName`, you can update that to get both `firstName` and `lastName` in single query like below ->

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameDB(Context context) throws SQLException {
this.con = new DatabaseHelper(context);

try {
    this.con.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {
    ;
}

if (!this.con.checkDataBase()) {
    return null;
} else {
    this.con.openDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.con.getWritableDatabase();

    for (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstName,lastName FROM tbl_doctor", (String[]) null); cursor.moveToNext(); this.firstName.add(cursor.getString(0)+" "+cursor.getString(1)) {

    }


    this.con.close();
    return this.firstName;

}

}
```

Now you can use this list in your adapter as below,

```
 ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    names = data.getNameDB(this);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names);

// set the adapter
list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

ask if you need any further help..

Comment: Instead of lastname, "true" appears beside the firstname

Comment: instead of data from lastname, a "true" text display beside the data of firstname instead of the data of lastname from my database.

Comment: updated my answer -> added this to query -> `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName"))`

Comment: still not displaying :( the output from the changes that you made is first data has no true while second data has true while third has no and so on...

Comment: see the update , it was my mistake, rectified it , let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to populate adapter in activity class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DataDB data = new DataDB();
ListView list;

ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

public MainActivity() {
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // set data

    ArrayList<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        firstName = data.getFNameDB(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> lastName = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        lastName = data.getLNameDB(this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finalList.addAll(firstName);
    finalList.addAll(lastName);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, finalList);

    // set the adapter
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

Comment: The lastName display at the bottom part of firstName. My goal is to display both in one listview and they are aligned to each other.